# How can I specify a piece of an image?

Tags: java, android

I'm doing work at Android Studio in which I need to place a graph inside an image. This image doesn't have the right proportions to insert in the graph. So I need help to put a specific part of an image in the center of the layout. How can I place the central area in the center of the layout?

graph over an image:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For graphs you should use [MP Charts library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)
 It runs on API level 8 and upwards.

Comment: I'm already using that library but I can't place that image at the center of the graph